# apache ssl redirect to a sub url path with FQDN intact?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

What I am trying to accomplish in Apache HTTP server (httpd.conf) is to redirect a user from a default page **http://www.abc.com/** to **https://www.abc.com/xxx?var1=1&var2=2** which also keeps FQDN intact.

How do I make this work in apache?
Below is my config setting in httpd.cof which is not working.

---

> RedirectMatch 301 / https://%{HTTP_HOST}/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/DMCInitialPageCmd?langId=-1&storeId=10001&catalogId=10051

- on the IE browser, testing the url access. eg: test.abc.com, how do I correctly display the hostname/fqdn? getting this response from the browser...

> https://%25{http_host}/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/DMCInitialPageCmd?langId=-1/storeId=10001/catalogId=10051?langId=-1&storeId=10001&catalogId=10051

Answer (score 0):

How is it failing?  I don't think that RedirectMatch accepted variable expansion (like `%{HTTP_HOST}`)...for this, I typically use `mod_rewrite`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/DMCInitialPageCmd?langId=-1&storeId=10001&catalogId=10051 [R=301]
```

Comment: I'll need to give your RedirectRule a try. By the way What does this exact syntax do "^/$"? Does this syntax only redirec the match default home page which is "index.htm"? This would be ideal case for me. Also, any sites that I can get some good examples on the usage of apache's reg express?

Comment: Will the above RewriteRule create a loop without using *RewriteCond* or the matching rule is suffice?